# External font not loading correctly CSS

Tags: css

My CSS custom font doesn't load onto the page when you load my website. At least, not until you click "home" or one of the other tabs. Anyone have any idea why this is and how to fix it? I used

```
@font-face {
font-family: OpenSansLight;
src: url(OpenSans-CondLight.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: OpenBold;
    src: url(OpenSans-CondBold.ttf);    
}

@font-face {
    font-family: OpenRegular;
    src: url(OpenSans-Regular.ttf); 
}
```

And

```
body, html{
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%; 
    font-family:"OpenSansLight";
}
```

The font doesn't load until I click a link within my website. Anyone have any idea why?

EDIT: Still trying to resolve this... No dice so far.

Second edit: People keep telling me to check if the font is in the right place. IT IS. And everything works. But not upon loading the page, for some unknown reason. hence my question. Please don't answer if you don't even read my question.

**Third edit:** Another few hours of fiddling have not resolved the issue. I tried expanding the support of the fonts by using

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenRegular';
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

But still, the same thing happens.
Noteworthy: Firebug greys out the font when inspecting it when it's not showing, but turns blue and kicks in when I click home or one of the other tabs and the font works.

**Fourth edit:** A few more days have passed and I'm still struggling with this problem. It's driving me insane. Please help me. I've tried every single possibility on W3C, Google results, Stack Overflow and every suggestion, yet nothing works for me. I'm sure my code is correct but it just won't load on the first try no matter what I try.

Comment: How are you including it in the `<head>` element in your html?

Comment: This is CSS. Not HTML.

Comment: @Reallyloudgirl br3w5 asked, how do you include it. Is this in the head, or a .css file? Does your fonts in the same directory as the css?

Comment: I link the stylesheet within the HTML head. And yes, the font works and the stylesheet works. But the font doesn't load when I open the page. It only loads after clicking a link within my page. Like I stated.... Twice...

Comment: We are trying to figure out, how do you included the css. You can do it with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">` but you can also copy it to the `<head><style>[styles comes here]</style></head>`. This is what we ask, how do you include it? Can you show us your live site?

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue in JSFiddle?

Comment: @Reallyloudgirl Have you tried? I can't see a link in your question. Here's a thought, have you tried resetting your Firefox settings?

Comment: I have tried multiple browsers, multiple computers. See what I mean for yourself. got to http://breunesse.info the name is admin and the password is concept

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the CSS file and the font files are in the same directory, if not either put them in the same directory or amend the CSS to have the correct path to the files

```
@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSansLight;
    src: url(path/to/OpenSans-CondLight.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: OpenBold;
    src: url(path/to/OpenSans-CondBold.ttf);    
}

@font-face {
    font-family: OpenRegular;
    src: url(path/to/OpenSans-Regular.ttf); 
}
```

Comment: My bad, anyway you must have had a cache problem then.. I suggest doing a hard reload (`ctr+shift+r` or `cmd+shift+r`) every time you make a major change in the css/js

Comment: No. I have this problem across multiple computers and browsers, as I said. Please read the full question before answering...